# Demo a presentation over the Internet in SlideShare

Tags: slideshare

[SlidePub](http://slidepub.com) offers a functionality named Remote Presenter that can be used to do a presentation over the Internet.

Can I use a similar functionality using SlideShare? If so, how? I can't find it on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SlideShare online presentation feature you are looking for is called [Zipcast](https://www.slideshare.net/AmitRanjan/zipcast-quick-tour/4-Zipcast_Free_or_PaidFree_Public). Zipcast has both a free version and a paid version. The paid version of Zipcast is included as a feature in the paid SlideShare PRO Account. The features of the free version of Zipcast are:

- Unlimited public meetings (ad-supported)
- Video & chat included

SlideShare Zipcast works in any modern browser. You can find instructions for how to start a web  meeting in Zipcast by visiting the link mentioned previously which links to a slide presentation called *Introducing Zipcast*.

Comment: Thanks, but $19/month??? This is too expensive for me, slidepub.com offers this for one tenth of the price.